# How to find path to localized directory?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I need to distribute a directory containing html files and images with my app.

The app has support for different languages. I have created a *directory* for each language and then pick the right one based on current locale:

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" 
                                                 ofType:@"html" 
                                            inDirectory:[language stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"html"];];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    // Fallback to english
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" 
                                           ofType:@"html" 
                                      inDirectory:@"en.html"];
}
```

*How can I better deal with this instead of having to do the above (which is a bit messy)?*

I'm thinking perhaps using the `xx.lproj` directories for this somehow and putting a localized html *directory* in each xx.lproj directory and use `NSBundle pathForResource` to find the correct file. Couldn't get it to work though.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `xx.lproj` folders with `[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` is straight-forward.

You can add `index.html` to your Xcode's project file and then make it localizable from its "Get Info" window. Add another language like "de", and Xcode will copy `index.html` into the newly created `de.lproj`. If you remove that file, the app will fall back on the English version.

You can test it with logging:

```
NSLog([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]);
```

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't being up voted.  If you use the path and URL methods of NSBundle, a lot of the hard work of figuring out your locale and region folders will be done for you automatically.

Comment: Because it doesn't work in XCode 6.3.2. That always returns nil, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I too am unable to get this to work:

```
    NSLog([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]);
```

But this does, using the standard Xcode language.lproj structure (e.g., en.lproj):

```
    NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" 
                  ofType:@"html" 
                  inDirectory:[language stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"lproj"]];
```

also removed extra ; in Martin's original question above ...

Answer (score 3):

Extra tip: make sure that you remove the unlocalized versions of the files in your built product, otherwise pathForResource will find those files instead of the localized ones.

Answer (score 1):

Why not the `forLocalization` way:

```
        htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myContent"
                                               ofType:@"html"
                                          inDirectory:@"de.lproj"
                                      forLocalization:@"de"];
```

This works fine here with Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS 7.1

Add the generalization of @Martin Wickman (with the fallback) and everything should be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"html_%@.html", NSLocalizedString(@"abbr", @"")];
```

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for.